# Excel function that combines hlookup and vlookup

Tags: excel, function, indexing, match

I need a function that will look up the datetime based on row 1 and column d..

so for EIM and Wk Start 1...it should bring up the value in E2

```
            EIM Infrastructure
```

January 1   Wk Start    Wk Start 1  1/28/2014 19:00 1/22/2014 19:00
    1   Wk End  Wk End 1    1/29/2014 5:00  1/23/2014 5:00
    1   We Start    We Start 1  1/17/2014 19:00 1/17/2014 19:00
    1   We End  We End 1    1/20/2014 5:00  1/20/2014 5:00
February    2   Wk Start    Wk Start 2  2/25/2014 19:00 2/26/2014 19:00
    2   Wk End  Wk End 2    2/26/2014 5:00  2/27/2014 5:00
    2   We Start    We Start 2  2/21/2014 19:00 2/28/2014 19:00
    2   We End  We End 2    2/24/2014 5:00  3/3/2014 5:00

Comment: It's not obvious what shape your data is in, please format it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the value at the intersection based on one criteria in a row and one in a column you can use `INDEX/MATCH/MATCH` - see [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html#IndexMatch2)

Comment: =INDEX(Sheet2!1:65536,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!1:65536,0),MATCH(B1,Sheet2!1:65536,0))

Comment: You should have just a single column for the first MATCH and a single row for the second, e.g. with row 1 and column D like you said that would be something like this: `=INDEX(E2:Z100,MATCH(A1,D2:D100,0),MATCH(B1,E1:Z1,0))`

Comment: but I have a table with muptiple rows and comumns of data

Comment: Yes, I understand that - but I'm assuming you have one criterion to match against a single row and one against a column, and you want to find the value at the intersection? That's what the suggested formula does - if A1 matches `D9`, for example and B1 matches `J1` then the formula returns the value at the intersection, i.e. the value in `J9` - can you format your example so that it's more readable, or attach a link to your sheet?